# finding data from a document with a array of strings/id in mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I have users, user_followers, and posts document.
I want to get a collection of the post posted by the followed users.

This is what I have thought I am not sure if it's the right way.

```
    UserFollowers.find({'user_id': req.decoded._id}, function(err, data) {
        userFollowers = data;
    });

    Post.paginate({'user_id': userFollowers.follower_id}, {page: page, limit: limit}, function(err, Posts) {
```

this the desired result.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Post found",
    "data": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "user_id": "5da5b54c90a96338cc847818",
                "_id": "5daedc59fdce1029bb02f6c5",
                "created_at": "2019-10-22T10:39:21.866Z",
                "picture": "YfeB9lHzc9m5ScAmFcMLDTC27DNjPx2Y.png",
                "caption": "Hello world",
                "__v": 1,
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "created_at": "2019-10-22T18:16:01.397Z",
                        "_id": "5daf4761fa981f794665a76c",
                        "comment": "testing comment",
                        "postedBy": "5d9ea2ae8a8af92d2102c129"
                    }

                ],
                "likes": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5db0568881630d23c22fa11b",
                        "likedBy": "5d9ea94f8a8af92d2102c12a"
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
}
```

Comment: Please share your collection

Comment: userFollowers
    ```
        {
                "user_id": "5d9ea2ae8a8af92d2102c129",
                "_id": "5daafe6dff6b130eb4b614a5",
                "created_at": "2019-10-19T12:15:41.641Z",
                "follower_id": "5d9ea94f8a8af92d2102c12a",
                "__v": 0
     }
```

Comment: You can use aggregate () and $group stage to group by users.